# Push Jenkins Build status to Github and Trigger Jenkins build from Github Webhook

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github

FYI - New to DevOps. Please bear with me. Thanks

I have a webhook created by Admin on Github Repo to trigger Jenkins build.
I created a token from my Github(I am not admin on the repo) and used it in Github Connection in Jenkins Configure.

Now if I commit when the token credentials are selected in Github in Jenkins Config, the Jenkins build is not triggered automatically. When I click on Build now the job is triggered and job status is pushed to Github.

If I don't select any credentials in Github in Jenkins Config, the jenkins build is triggered on commit but the build status is not reflecting in Github.

There is a manage hooks options also in Github in Jenkins Configure but that probably would require a token from Admin on repo?

Can you guys guide me on what should I do now to 
1. Trigger the Jenkins Build on commit.
2. Push the build status to Github.

Thanks

Comment: The "manage hooks" option is almost certainly the easiest. That said, it seems strange to me that you are trying to set up webhooks on a repo that you are not an admin for.  That's kind of like trying to do repairs or upgrades on a car that is not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering Jenkins using GitHub webhook should be a straight forward process. This [article](https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae) would help you.

Comment: it would be better to point to [Jenkins' own guide to setting things up for GitHub](https://jenkins.io/solutions/github/).

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. Certificates were needed to be installed which was blocking connection to Github Enterprise. Once I installed those, the setup is working fine now.

Thanks Everyone. :)